# How to return a bitmap to a browser WebApi

Tags: c#, javascript, image, asp.net-web-api

I am making a request to the server "WebApi" using JavaScript from an already loaded document on the client side.

When the server receives the request it builds a bitmap on the fly and returns it back to the client as a .png.

When i read the response on the client side all I get back from the data portion of the .ajax request is an empty string.

How can I read and image requested from a server using WebApi and then set the src attribute of a image on the client side with the new image received from the server?

--WebApi

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        ElevationResponse elev = ElevationHelper.GetElevation(id);

        Bitmap canvas = ShopDrawing.Elevation.Elevation.GetShopDrawing(elev, true);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        canvas.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        HttpResponseMessage r = Request.CreateResponse();
        r.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
        r.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        return r;
    }
```

--Client

```
  $.ajax(
         {
             async: true,
             url: '/api/drawings?id=' + this.id,
             type: 'GET',
             contentType: "application/json",
             success: function (d, status) {
                 debugger

             }
         });
```

Comment: Why the AJAX? Couldn't you simply specify `'/api/drawings?id=' + this.id` as image src?

Comment: Thats perfect. I've updated my client to:   document.body.querySelector("#elev").src = '/api/drawings?id=' + this.id; After the round trip from the server the image only shows up as a broken image icon, you know the default for broken images. Do I have my c# webapi code correct?

Comment: I think you should reset the memory stream to the beginning, and also specify `Content.Headers.ContentLength`. If this does not work, enter the url directly in your browser and enable the developer tools to view the network traffic.

Comment: I summarized it in an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: Dispose the bitmap too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply specify `'/api/drawings?id=' + this.id` as image `src` attribute.

On the server side, you should reset the memory stream after `canvas.Save()` so that it will be sent from the beginning. Also, specify the http `Content-Length` header so that browsers know the total size while downloading:

```
ms.Position = 0;
r.Content.Headers.ContentLength = ms.Length;
```

If this does not work, enter the url directly in your browser and enable the developer tools to view the network traffic.

Comment: After `canvas.Save()`. It's like a cassette recorder: Record, rewind, play back. ,

Comment: This was a huge help. Thank you.